# SQL columns based on select values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, create-table

Would like to get data with preferably one query, but columns are dynamical based on selected values.

So my tables look like this (using MySql):

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `income` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `action_a` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `action_b` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `action_c` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `given` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Would like to get in one query table that look something like this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| day | action_a | action_b | action_c | user_B   | user_C   |
+------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 123 | 123.01   | 123.01   | 123.01   |  123.01  | -123.01  |
| 122 | 324.02   | 234.01   | 123.01   | -123.01  | -123.01  |
| 121 | 987.00   | 345.01   | 123.01   |  123.01  | -123.01  |
| 120 | 9393.01  | 456.01   | 123.01   | -123.01  | -123.01  |
| 119 | 0.00     | 567.01   | 123.01   | -123.01  | -123.01  |
 ...
```

*Negative values in user columns means user gave to other user*

Currently I'm doing 3 separate queries and afterwards merging data, but my current queries look like this:

Get action based income

```
Select action_a, action_b, action_c From income i Join users u on u.id=i.user Where u.name='%s' and i.day=%i Order by i.id desc
```

Get received

```
Select u2.name 'from', amount From given g Join users u on u.id = to_user Join users u2 on u2.id = from_user Where u.name='%s' and amount <> 0.0 Order by g.id
```

Get given

```
Select u2.name 'to', amount From given g Join users u on u.id = from_user Join users u2 on u2.id = to_user Where u.name='%s' and amount <> 0.0 Order by g.id desc
```

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/265f1a9/1)

Comment: Can you add some data as well for the tables? A SQLFiddle link with sample data will be very helpful as well.

Comment: Concur, starting sample data is required here (or, _maybe_ how you merge the data), especially for to/from users.  Note that I'm expecting this to be some form of running sum/calculation query, which MySQL lacks built-in operators to perform nicely (that is, I expect the query would normally be performed via windowing functions)

Comment: @clinomaniac added sql fiddle link

Comment: What's the value expected in `user_B` and `user_C`?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design, so seriously consider revising your schema design

Comment: @clinomaniac username

Comment: @Strawberry maybe You have suggestions?

Comment: @Mortin How is `123.01` a username?

Comment: @clinomaniac That's table for user_A. Day 123 He/she got 123.01 from user_B, on day 122 he/she gave 123.01 to user_B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of normalised income/income_action tables might be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE income 
(income_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,dt datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
,user INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE income_action 
(income_id INT NOT NULL
,action CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,value DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
,PRIMARY KEY(income_id,action)
);
```